# Java. Поиск слов (или элементов) на изображении. Без машинного обучения

Tags: java, изображения, opensource

Интересует такой вопрос: есть ли open source библиотеки, сервисы и тп, которые могли бы выделить, дать координаты слов или же просто объектов без распознавания текста.

[image: что-то типа этого]

Answer (score 4):

Смотри в сторону OpenCV - мощный инструмент для работы с графикой и не только.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел еще один простой вариант - использовать библиотеку "Tesseract".
Tesseract OCR API умеет распознавать текст и выводить его координаты.
Для этого:

1. Подключаем библиотеку [Tess4J Tesseract For Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j)
2. Качаем [traineddata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata), тут [русский](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/rus.traineddata) язык.
3. Простенький код для примера:

   Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
   // помещаем traineddata по пути "C:/TESSERACT/tessdata"
   // а в "setDatapath" указываем неполный путь
   instance.setDatapath("C:/TESSERACT/");
   // указываем язык
   instance.setLanguage("rus");
   // страница
   File page = new File("path);
   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(page);
   // получаем координаты текста в виде Rectangle = {x:12, y:34, height:60, width:120}
   // параметр size отвечает за размер блоков
   // чем больше size, тем мельче будет биться блок с текстом
   List segmentedRegions = instance.getSegmentedRegions(image, size);
   for(Rectangle rectangle : segmentedRegions) {
       // получили координаты блоков с текстом
   }